# Enum does not with for switch statement

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to switch states. I first start off in the START_STATE. I then prompt the user to whether go to the FAIL_STATE or GO_STATE. However it seems that whether they type in "go" (For the GO_STATE) for fail (for the FAIL_STATE), neither of the other cases are activated. What is a solution for this issue?

```
import java.util.*;

public class dfa {
      static State state;


public enum State 
   {
        START_STATE,
         GO_STATE,
         FAIL_STATE,
         };


dfa(State state)
 { state = this.state;}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;

    state = State.START_STATE;   
        switch(state)
            {
            case START_STATE:

                System.out.print("In start state \n ");
                System.out.println("Which state you want to go to? \n");
                line = input.next();
                if(line.equals("go"))
                {
                    state = State.GO_STATE;
                    System.out.print(" Go hello");
                }
                else if(line.equals("fail"))
                {
                    state = State.FAIL_STATE;
                System.out.println(" Fail hello ");
                }
                 break;
                case FAIL_STATE:  
                System.out.println("fail state");
                break;
                case GO_STATE:
                System.out.println("go state");
               break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Default");
                break;
            }


    System.out.println("made it here");





    }

}
```

Output:

```
(When "go" is typed)
Go hello 
made it here

(When "fail" is typed)
Fail hello 
made it here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `case START_STATE` don't have a `break`. Then it will always go to next case witch is `case FAIL_STATE:` witch has a `break`.

Your `switch-case` should follow this order.

```
switch(condition){
    case con1:
     // do something
    break;
    case con2:
     // do something
    break;
    default:
    // do something
    break;        

}
```

Comment: Added the break, but program does not go to either of the states for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot a `break` in the case for the START_STATE:

```
case START_STATE:
    System.out.print("In start state \n ");
    System.out.println("Which state you want to go to? \n");
    line = input.next();
    if(line.equals("go")) {
        state = State.GO_STATE;
        System.out.print(" Go hello");
    } else if(line.equals("fail")) {
        state = State.FAIL_STATE;
        System.out.println(" Fail hello ");
    }
    break; // <-- here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `break` statement at the end of the `case START_STATE`, so it just falls through to the next `case`:

```
case START_STATE:
    System.out.print("In start state \n ");
    System.out.println("Which state you want to go to? \n");
    line = input.next();
    if(line.equals("go"))
    {
        state = State.GO_STATE;
        System.out.print(" Go hello");
    }
    else if(line.equals("fail"))
    {
        state = State.FAIL_STATE;
        System.out.println(" Fail hello ");
    }
    break; // Missing from OP
```